# How does one produce a specific unicode character with Python's C-API?

Tags: python, unicode, python-c-api

I'm writing a Python extension that runs through a Py_UNICODE array, finds specific (ASCII, if it matters) characters, i.e. '\' or '\n', and does some additional stuff for each one that it finds.

Is there a way to write those characters as literals?  If not, what is the correct way to obtain Py_UNICODEs for them, keeping in mind that Py_UNICODE's size and internal representation may differ from system to system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PyUnicode_FromWideChar()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_FromWideChar) or one of the [built-in codec decode functions](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#built-in-codecs).